# Dynamically put condition with the array as per the array value

Tags: php

I have the below array. I want to put condition dynamically as per the sections are coming.

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [content_form] => Array
            (
                [0] => genre
                [1] => cast
                [2] => category
            )

        [content_type] => stdClass Object
            (
                [genre] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => History
                        [1] => ACTION
                        [2] => ROMANTIC
                    )

                [cast] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 13128
                        [1] => 13127
                    )

                [category] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 4119
                        [1] => 4118
                        [2] => 4081
                    )

            )

        [conditions] => Array
            (
                [0] => OR
                [1] => AND
            )

        )
```

In the above array for content_form there are 3 array values and in 0th index genre, 1st index cast and 2nd index category present.

Similarly for content_type there are 3 array values present and in the last array conditions present.

My requirement is that as per the section coming I want to put condition with them.
    Example- ((genre OR cast) AND category)

similarly if my output is like below then the condition will be
    Example - (genre OR cast)

```
        [content_form] => Array
        (
            [0] => genre
            [1] => cast
        )

    [content_type] => stdClass Object
        (
            [genre] => Array
                (
                    [0] => History
                    [1] => ACTION
                    [2] => ROMANTIC
                )

            [cast] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13128
                    [1] => 13127
                )

        )

    [conditions] => Array
        (
            [0] => OR
        )

    )
```

And if my output is like the below then there will no condition with any other key and it will return the simple result.

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [content_form] => Array
        (
            [0] => cast
        )

    [content_type] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cast] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13128
                    [1] => 13127
                )

        )

    [conditions] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

How I can do this dynamically as per the sections are coming as per sequence with the array of content_type and conditions?

Comment: Why not `(genre OR (cast AND category)` ?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @splash58, As genre comes first sequence then cast  and in last category. so as per the sequence the combination will be ((genre OR cast) AND category)

Comment: @Nick , My expected output for the first sequence should be 
   (([genre] => Array
                (
                    [0] => History
                    [1] => ACTION
                    [2] => ROMANTIC
                )] OR  [cast] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13128
                    [1] => 13127
                )] ) AND ([category] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4119
                    [1] => 4118
                    [2] => 4081
                )])

Comment: I'm more interested in how this array was created. stdClass looks a bit strange for me, i strongly remember stdClass being somewhere from C++.

Comment: @PrakashKumarGuru should be ???

Comment: @Nick , I have updated my answer

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin , It is a json object and inside this  array value present. So decoding we can get the output like the above

Comment: This is starting to look like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The output format you want doesn't make any sense how do you plan to use it?

Comment: @Nick , No, It is not a XY problem. As the value will come only in this mentioned format. there will be no change for the output. We need to make the combination as per the mentioned keys and values

Comment: Still I can't get any solution. could anyone please help me on it

Comment: @PrakashKumarGuru If you are satisfied with my answer. Could you please approve my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done this. Please check:

```
$jsonData = '{"content_form":["genre","cast","category", "prakash"],"content_type":{"genre":["History","ACTION","ROMANTIC"],"cast":["13128","13127"],"category":["4119","4118","4081"]},"conditions":["OR","AND","OR"]}';
$contentIds = array(
    'genre'=>array(1,2,3),
    'cast'=>array(1,2,4),
    'category'=>array(3,2,7),
    'prakash'=>array(1,2,3,8,9)
);
$arrayDecode = json_decode($jsonData,true);
$result = array();
foreach($arrayDecode['conditions'] as $key=>$val){
    if($result){
        $secondArr = $contentIds[$arrayDecode['content_form'][$key+1]];
        $result  = array_merge($result, $secondArr); 
    } else {
        $firstArr = $contentIds[$arrayDecode['content_form'][$key]];
        $secondArr = $contentIds[$arrayDecode['content_form'][$key+1]];
        $result  = array_merge($firstArr, $secondArr);
    }
    if($val=='OR'){
        $result = array_unique($result);
    } else {
        $result = array_diff_assoc($result, array_unique($result));
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

Let me know this is your requirement or not?

Comment: Thank you so much @Developer, The logic you have mentioned works perfectly as per my requirements.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer. Could you please approve my answer :)